# Why is gcc 4.8.1 giving me the ">> should be > > within a nested templated list" error? Wasn't this fixed in C++11?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

I just got

```
error: ‘>>’ should be ‘> >’ within a nested template argument list
  std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>> AllConfiguration;
```

Wasn't this fixed in C++11 ?

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
```

I am on C++11

Comment: You need to compile in C++11 mode: `-std=c++11`.

Comment: "I am on C++11" - sound like you are on some drug :) But seriously: `gcc` should be `g++`. And are you *really* sure you used `-std=c++11`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you compiling this correctly?

try this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o program program.cpp
```